# Updating WebGL Textures in WebAssembly from HTMLVideoElement

Tags: javascript, video, webgl, webassembly

I have a [project](https://github.com/Shachlan/webassembly-webgl-shaders)* in which I play two videos, run a simple shader that shows edges and blends them, and display the result in a canvas. The project is based on [this tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-webgl-shaders-in-webassembly-1e6c5effc813). The goal I try to achieve is to understand whether running on JS and WebAssembly is faster than just WebGL work in JS, but at the moment I'm switching between JS and WebAssembly on every frame, which seems to be very expensive.

In every frame the code copies the content of each HTMLVideoElement into a WebGL texture in JS:

```
export function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,
    level,
    internalFormat,
    srcFormat,
    srcType,
    video
  );
}
```

and then calls WebAssembly in order to process the content of the textures.
Now, I see that the time cost of texture copying is quite expensive, and if I understand the system correctly, there's also a cost to the constant switches between JS and WASM.

Is there a way to copy the current video frame in WASM, in order to save the back-and-forth between JS and WASM? The only way I see is to add usage of codecs, and I'd like to keep using higher-level interfaces.

*If you want to run the project, call 'grunt exec', 'npm run copy-assets', 'npm run dev'. Use the 'texture-copying' branch.

Comment: What are you doing in WASM? Copying a video to a texture may or may not be slow. It's up to the browser in how that operation is implemented. Once you get back to WASM though what are you doing? Are you calling `gl.readPixels` to get the video out? If so that is the slowest part for sure. If possible why not just upload the videos in JS and then use shaders to process them. What is WASM doing for you here? The only reason to use WASM is to get faster CPU processing. But if all you're doing is uploading videos and running shaders then switching to WASM will be no benefit.

Comment: I'm just running shaders in WASM, without reading the pixels. 
The whole exercise is meant to check whether WASM provides a better alternative than running WebGL in the browser.
"if all you're doing is uploading videos and running shaders then switching to WASM will be no benefit." - can you please give me a source for this? This is the core of what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: WASM does not provide a better alternative unless you're doing something that WASM excels at which is CPU intensive. Calling WebGL 2 or 3 times a frame to process video with shaders will have zero benefit in WASM. An example where WASM would excel, Physics simulation (CPU intensive). Another example might be height map based realtime terrain generation with lodding (CPU intensive). Another example might be large scene culling (CPU intensive). Calling a few shaders is not CPU intensive so no benefit.

Comment: It might also be worth doing in a case where you know you have a CPU but no GPU or where you know the GPU is busy with stuff and you want to utilize the CPU at the same time instead of wait around for the GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that compiling to Asm.JS instead of WASM removes the cost of the context switches, thus fixing my issue. 
It's not a perfect solution, but it still provides better performance than JS.